# jQuery switching event handler between click and hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I know I can add and remove even handlers with `on` and `off`.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have responsive navigation that works on `click` on touch devices and on `hover` on desktops.

My code works when I resize the window from small to large but doesn't work (can't unbind hover handler) when scaling down.

I am using bootstrap's dropdown menu if that helps.

```
  enableHover : function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').off();
    $('.dropdown-toggle').parent().on({ //parent needed for hover
        mouseenter: function() {
          $(this).addClass('open').find('ul').show();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
          $(this).removeClass('open').find('ul').hide();
        }
    });

  },
  disableHover : function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').parent().off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
  }
```

Comment: When do `enableHover` and `disableHover` get called?

Comment: They are called on window resize. If the width is less than > 768 -> disableHover if < 768 -> enableHover.

Comment: You're saying that `disableHover` doesn't fire even if the width is actually less than 768?  Are you sure it is?

Comment: `disableHover` fires but the hover handlers isn't cleared. It should be replaced by `click`.

Comment: Where do you try to replace it with `click`/

Comment: $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); - bootstrap's plugin. And it works when I reload a page.

Answer (score 0):

Using a class instead of `hide` & `show` method solved the problem.